# TS: how in general get type of returned object by argument property

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

Suppose we have the following types

```
type ALL = 'AA' | 'BB' | 'CC';
type AA = { a: number; };
type BB = { b: string; };
type CC = { c: boolean; };
type MyArg = { type: ALL };
```

I was try to create mapper for `type name` <=> `type` like

```
type ReturnMap = {
  'AA': AA;
  'BB': BB;
  'CC': CC;
}
```

And function `hook` that must return object, depends on argument type

```
const hook = (g: MyArg) => {
  const some = {};
  ...// some calculations here
  return some as ReturnMap[g.type];
};
```

But catch an TS error on the row with `return` statement

```
Type 'any' cannot be used as an index type.
```

If modify return like this

```
const hook = (g: MyArg) => {
  const some = {};
  ...// some calculations here
  return some as ReturnMap[typeog g['type']];
};
```

The type of returned object in case

```
const answ = hook({ type: 'BB' });
```

will be `AA | BB | CC`, but I want to `BB` only;

Answer (score 1):

Please remember that type system of TypeScript runs when you compile the program to JavaScript. When it's in JavaScript (nearly) all types are gone from your code.

Also values in your code are not known before you run the compiled JavaScript program, long after TypeScript compiler finished its job.

So you can't make types dependent on values that are not known till the program is running. The only values that can influence your types are the ones that you narrowed down in your code editor before any of your code actually runs.

You can do something like what you are trying to do but I suspect it won't have anywhere near the functionality you seek:

```
var map: {
    'AA': { a: number },
    'BB': { b: string },
    'CC': { c: boolean }
};

function h<T extends 'AA' | 'BB' | 'CC'>(ty: T): typeof map[T] {
    return {} as any;
}


var q = h('BB');
// q is of type { b: string } but only because argument ty was given as string literal of specific value
```

Here you can see [working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/G4QwTgBAtiAOBcEDeBYAUBTECC3FIhEQDsBXKAIwFNIBfAGnSwgCEX8ILEBnAFzACWxAOYQGTLAGFJHAMaIKAe0UAbKiGJj0tANzp0AM1LFZvAYs0ALADwAVCFQAevKsQAm3CAHJcXiAB9vNj9Ar2kvAD4ACl4AT0RbAEpEONgqRQNoOABtWwBdZAlMMCpeUjBNJFpCTw1YvTRafTR0UEgARwgAXghLKIAiNn7EhoB6UYhOgU8MiFSqZE4efiFRaopSXggLFVjOKlkQUm4F8GFyVy24iAB3EE9hAWBXGog%20QREIFQEXMBAVbaZbhpWQCAwCWQQUAqUhUdBAA). Please note how compiled JavaScript code is devoid of all the type information and any logic associated with the types.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it in the following way

```
type ReqTypes = 'AA' | 'BB';
type ReqGenModel = {
  msg: string;
  type: ReqTypes;
};

type ReqGen1Props = { a: string, b: string };
const reqGen1 = (props: ReqGen1Props): ReqGenModel => {
  return {
    msg: props.a + props.b,
    type: 'AA',
  };
};

type ReqGen2Props = { a: string };
const reqGen2 = (props: ReqGen2Props): ReqGenModel => {
  return {
    msg: props.a + '-DEFAULT',
    type: 'BB',
  };
};
```

Then defined `getHook` function with overloads

```
const c = (x: any): unknown => c;

function getHook(arg: ReturnType<typeof reqGen1>): AA;
function getHook(arg: ReturnType<typeof reqGen2>): BB;
function getHook(arg) {
  const b = c(arg);

  return b;
};
```

So

```
const ty = getHook(reqGen1({a: 'ggg', b: 'cc'}));
// const ty: AA
enter code here
```

UPDATE:

```
type ResReturn<T> = T extends ReturnType<typeof reqGen1>
  ? AA
  : T extends ReturnType<typeof reqGen2>
    ? BB
    : never;

function getHookV2<T>(arg: T): ResReturn<T> {
  const b: any = c(arg);

  return b;
};

const hhh = getHookV2(reqGen1({a: 'ggg', b: 'cc'}));
// const hhh: AA
```

Comment: It might be cleaner if you defined return types of `reqGen1` and `reqGen2` ahead of time and gave them names.